# GoogleSignInClient return 8 (internal error)

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm trying to connect my game to Google Play Games Services, but when I try to login, it always returns me an error code 8 (internal error). 
The code is copy pasted from [Google example:](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/TypeANumber/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/tanc/MainActivity.java)

```
lateinit var signInClient: GoogleSignInClient

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_settings)
    settings_login.setOnClickListener { login() }
    signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
            GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).build()
    )
}

private fun login() {
    startActivityForResult(signInClient.signInIntent, 9001)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode != 9001) {
        return
    }

    val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(intent)

    try {
        val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
        onConnected(account)
    } catch (apiException: ApiException) {
        var message: String? = apiException.message
        if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
            message = getString(R.string.signin_other_error)
        }

        onDisconnected()

        AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                .show()
    }
}
```

In Google Play Console I've linked my game with debug keystore SHA-1.
I've checked everythin mentioned in [Troubleshooting guide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting), but I still get this message again and again. 
Does someone faced this issue? Any ideas how to debug it?
EDIT: 
I found that it actually logs me in - if I restart game, method `signInSilently()` will be successful. However, it still shows this error 8 when I logout and try to log in manually. Could it be the problem with login activity overlay?
Oh, and I checked api access in Google Play Api Console - it shows that api actually receives my calls and it doesn't mention any errors.[image: See screenshot]
EDIT 2: I've added `requestEmail()` to `GoogleSignInOptions.Builder`, and it shows me overlay with access request. However, it still fails in `GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(intent).getResult(ApiException::class.java)` with same error (8 - internal error).

Comment: Can you show the error logs?

Comment: Hi @noogui, there is nothing obvious in logs. I turned GMS logs on with command `adb shell setprop log.tag.Games VERBOSE`, and here is whole log since `startActivityForResult` call: https://pastebin.com/sphq9NcT

Comment: do you work with emulator or real device

Comment: Hi @Boe-Dev it's real device, Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 7.0

Comment: @noktigula as I rember I had a problem like this with the wrong emulator, but I am sorry for now I have no idea

Answer (score 5):

It looks like this bug in Google Play Services 12.2.21:

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/358

Google is supposed to be working on a fix for release over the air soon..

Answer (score 3):

it's maybe late but I found the reason. It fixed in my case and I see your code has same problem.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    ...

    val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(intent) 
    ...
}
```

The intent you passed to the method getSignedInAccountFromIntent() is not the intent that returned by onActivityResult. The intent you passed come from activity, so you need to change it to

```
val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
```

"data" is the intent returned by onActivityResult

Comment: Thank so much, you save my time. I met the same issue with you. 

Answer (score 1):

I didn't found the reason of this error, but I found an (ugly) workaround. I noticed, that when I restart game after manual login, even if there was this error, `signInSilently()` method works fine, which means that API actually authenticate me and fails later. So in `catch` block I'm checking for status code of error, and, if it's (8 - internal error), I'm requesting last signed in account. If account is present, I assume user to be logged in. 
It's really dirty but I'm out of ideas.

```
//onActivityResult
val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(intent)

try {
    val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
    onSuccess(account)
} catch (apiException: ApiException) {
    val acc = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context)
    if (apiException.statusCode == 8 && acc != null && acc.email != null) {
        onSuccess(account)
    } else {
        onFail(apiException)
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work for me... getLastSignedInAccount returns null after INTERNAL_ERROR...

Answer (score 0):

I have a client with that error. Only ONE! With a Galaxy S9. Nothing happens when clicking on the Sign In button (startActivityForResult -> GoogleSignIn.getClient.getSignInIntent)